# Updating XML based on changes in HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, xml, xslt

I have a new assignment which is wrinkling my brain. We create reports for auditing purposes, and save the file as HTML, and XML (to be used with XSLT). Those files are modified by few other guys, later on, and they don't have knowledge to edit XML files. So, I need help to make sure that changes are made on both XML and HTML files.

To explain it in less confusing manner, I want to allow user to modify HTML file, and the same changes should reflect in XML. I can use JavaScript to post form data, and modify XML on submit. Or I can attach ASP.Net script to do the same. But, right now, I am confused as to where to start, which scripting language will be a good idea, or if I should use form or hidden variables.

So, any help of any kind is appreciated here, as I am totally out of my depth here.

Edit:

So, I tried few things on my end. Turns out, we have a vb.net application, in which the HTML is displayed. So, it was easy to get the HTML data back to vb.net. Now, I have a vb.net String "strHTMLData" which contains the updated value for an HTML text field.

But, I can't figure out how to write this string to an existing node in XML. I can write it in a new file, just fine. But, finding the existing node and updating the value is getting too tricky.

For example:

```
        Dim reader As XmlTextReader = New XmlTextReader("Test.Xml")
    Dim writer As XmlTextWriter = New XmlTextWriter("Test2.Xml", System.Text.Encoding.Unicode)


    writer.WriteNode(reader, True)
```

This works fine, and the writer creates a Test2.Xml as an exact copy of Test.Xml.

```
        Do While (reader.Read())
        Select Case reader.NodeType
            Case XmlNodeType.Element 'Display beginning of element.
                'Code to change node element
            Case XmlNodeType.Text 'Display the text in each element.
                'Code to change node value
                If reader.Name = "Summary" Then
                    writer.WriteValue("Edited Summary")
                End If
        End Select
    Loop
```

This on the other hand, doesn't work. There is no error at all, but node "Summary" doesn't get updated.

Answer (score 0):

Changes take place in the page, you post changes, fetch xml and update it. Now what you have against that.

Comment: I don't know how to update the said XML. That's what I have against it. I have no idea how to update an XML file from within a code. 

I got the data from the HTML document to a VB.Net string. Now what?

Comment: Tried XMlDocument. This is the error received "Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.". 

This is the code

    Dim document As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument
        document.LoadXml("Test.Xml")
Also, I tried using XMlReader and XmlWriter. But those didn't help. I added the code for same in the question.

Comment: Then check if your xml document is well formatted (e.g has one root, etc..)

Comment: It is. This is an existing XML file, used in same project in multiple places. They just read the file though, this is first time it is to be modified.

Comment: Since error is on line one position 1 then make sue the unicode format of the file is correct and compatible, i faced such an issue before related to unicode format of the file having extra weird 3 characters ï"¿ in utf-8 files.

Comment: I used "<item>something</item>" within the code itself, and it worked. When I moved just this line to XML file, it didn't. There is literally nothing but a single node in the xml file, and still the same problem.

Edit: Found the issue. I am using LoadXml, instead of Load. Anyway, now to get node data and update them. Wish me luck.